# phpMySQL Should be working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is a private message system. It should be inserting data into the table, but it is not at all.. Thanks for the help.

**Sql Error**: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, body, subject, date_sent VALUES('itunes89','itunes89','sd','s','9-05-2012 ' at line 1

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pm_inbox (to_user, from, body,subject,date_sent)VALUES('$userIdFromPost','$user','$body','$sub','$date')";
mysql_query($sql);
echo "Error: " . mysql_error($con);
echo "<br/>Inserted: '$userIdFromPost','$user','$body','$sub','$date'";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a `)` after your column list. Please refrain from using `mysql_` functions. Use prepared statements with either `mysqli` or `PDO` like so:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO pm_inbox (to_user, from, body, subject, date_sent) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)"); 
$stmt->bind_param($userIdFromPost,$user,$body,$sub,$date);
```

Further, `from` is a [reserved name](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. It needs to be encased like so:

```
(to_user, `from`, body, subject, date_sent)
```

Comment: No, I have never used that with mysql. It works fine everywhere else.

Comment: It takes two more minuets. I will.

Answer (score 1):

You've missed a closing parenthesis:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pm_inbox (to_user, from, body, subject, date_sent VALUES('$userIdFromPost','$user','$body','$sub','$date')";
```

should be

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pm_inbox (to_user, from, body, subject, date_sent) VALUES('$userIdFromPost','$user','$body','$sub','$date')";
```

Comment: I changed it, it still broken.

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, body, subject, date_sent)VALUES('itunes89','itunes89','sd','s','9-05-2012 ' at line 1